# Get Retweets Count from user timeline

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collections of **twitter tweets** of my own stored in mongodb using twitter api **'statuses/user_timeline'**. Am trying to get the **retweets** count I've got on the tweets posted by me using **MongoDb MapReduce** method but not able to get it. Can anyone please help me out.

**Sample Data:** this is the format of document stored in mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570664d7a9c29761168b4587"),
    "created_at" : "Thu Sep 17 01:17:28 +0000 2015",
    "id" : NumberLong("644319222886039556"),
    "id_str" : "644319222886039556",
    "text" : "Be silent or let your words be worth more than you silence.",
    "entities" : {
        "hashtags" : [ ],
        "symbols" : [ ],
        "user_mentions" : [ ],
        "urls" : [ ]
    },
    "truncated" : false,
    "source" : "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>",
    "in_reply_to_status_id" : null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str" : null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id" : null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str" : null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name" : null,
    "user" : {
        // Here is the user information who tweeted
        "id" : NumberLong(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx),
        "id_str" : "xxxxxxxxx",
        "name" : "Haridarshan Gorana",
        "screen_name" : "haridarshan2901"
    },
    "geo" : null,
    "coordinates" : null,
    "place" : null,
    "contributors" : null,
    "is_quote_status" : false,
    "retweet_count" : NumberLong(1),
    "favorite_count" : NumberLong(0),
    "favorited" : false,
    "retweeted" : false,
    "lang" : "en"
}
```

**Code:**

```
$map = new \MongoCode("function() { emit(this.id_str, this.retweet_count); }");
$out = "retweets";
$reduce = new \MongoCode('function(key, values) {
    var retweets = 0;
    for(i=0;i<values.length;i++){

        if( values[i].retweet_count > 0 ){
            retweets += values[i].retweet_count;
        }

    }
    return retweets;
}');
$verbose = true;
$cmd = array(
    "map" => $map,
    "reduce" => $reduce,
    "query" => $query,
    "out" => "retweets",
    "verbose" => true
);

$result = $db->command($cmd);

print_r($result);
```

this gives me this error

**Fatal error: Call to a member function command() on null**

Same code I've tried to run on mongo client

```
var mapFunction1 = function() {
    emit(this.id_str, this.retweet_count);
}

var reduceFunction1 = function(id, values) { 
    var retweet = 0; 
    for(i=0;i<values.length;i++){ 
        if(values[i].retweet_count > 0) { 
            retweet += values[i].retweet_count;
        } 
    } 
    return retweet;  
}

db.tweets.mapReduce(
    mapFunction1, 
    reduceFunction1, 
    {
        query: { 
            user: { id: xxxxxxxxx }
        }, 
        out: "retweets", 
        verbose: true
    }
)
```

**Output from console**

```
{
    "result" : "retweets",
    "timeMillis" : 12,
    "timing" : {
        "mapTime" : 0,
        "emitLoop" : 8,
        "reduceTime" : 0,
        "mode" : "mixed",
        "total" : 12
    },
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 0,
        "emit" : 0,
        "reduce" : 0,
        "output" : 0
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include some sample documents and your expected result to show what you want achieved with the MapReduce operation? I have a strong feeling that your problem can be easily resolved using aggregation framework with some great performance enhancements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reducer is trying to call a property `retweet_count` when all that is there is just a "value" with no other property. You already referenced that in the mapper.

Actually your reduce can simply be:

```js
function(key,values) {
    return Array.sum(values)
}
```

But you would be better off simply using `.aggregate()` for this. Not only is it more simple, but it's just going to run a lot faster:

```js
db.tweets.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$user.id_str",
    "retweets": { "$sum": "$retweet_count" }
  }}
])
```

Or for PHP

```js
$collection->aggregate(
    array(
        '$group' => array(
           '_id' => '$user.id_str',
           'retweets' => array( '$sum' => '$retweet_count' )
        )
    )
)
```

If you want to add a "query" to that then add a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline stage at the begining. i.e.

```js
$collection->aggregate(
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            'user.id_str' => 'xxxxxxxxx'
        )
    ),    
    array(
        '$group' => array(
           '_id' => '$user.id_str',
           'retweets' => array( '$sum' => '$retweet_count' )
        )
    )
)
```

You should really only use `mapReduce` when the structure actually **needs** JavaScript control for processing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've never worked with Mongo before, so can you pleas tell If I've collection of tweets of multiple user and want to use this aggregate method on tweets of only one user, how will i use this method. In the sample tweet in user object, i do have **user id** and **twitter screen_name**